# link problems when using a test dll and a production dll

Tags: boost, boost-test

I want to write unit tests for internal components of a DLL, and in the testing project I can only access exported symbols. I want to test internal classes also, and I don't want to export them just for the tests. 
I'm using boost test, visual studio 10 and dynamic linking. The message I get is

```
fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Copy&paste the whole error message you get. That is, *what* unresolved external did the linker encounter.

Comment: The unresolved externals are the methods I want to test. In my project structure I have a production DLL and a unit test DLL. In the unit test code I use internal production classes which are not externalized, so it makes sense to have link problems. I want to avoid declaring the production code as external, yet unit test them, and organize the test code and the production code with a clear separation.